# Disable html5 video download at CSS breakpoint

Tags: css, html5-video

I have a short looping html5 video that plays automatically in the browser. When the browser width is reduced to 870px the video disappears thanks to a css media query and display:none;

How do I ensure the video does not download if the window starts at a smaller size like on a mobile device?

The video is 1.8mb and I don't want to unnecessarily tax my user's data usage. Thanks!

```
<video id="video_background" preload="none" autoplay="false" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
<source src="video/creativeishappening.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Video not supported
</video>
```

---

```
$(function() {

// onload
if(document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
    $('video').attr('autoplay', true);
}

});
```

Comment: Just don't autoplay it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video playing automatically is due to the "autoplay" attribute in the  tag.

So you want the video autoplay depending on the window size when loaded. So you can add the attribute manually, like below:

```
$(function() {

    // onload
    if(document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
        $('video').attr('autoplay', true);
    }

    // If you want to autoplay when the window is resized wider than 780px 
    // after load, you can add this:

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
            $('video').attr('autoplay', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good answer. It's not working for me though. I made the video visible at all browser widths for testing purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I lost the rest of my first comment somehow. The video is now playing at every width in chrome and is not playing at all in firefox. I posted the exact code I'm using above. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I found the point, you should delete autoplay="false" at all in you html tag. In your case it meant to autoplay it. Because the browser only decide to autoplay when it HAS THE AUTOPLAY ATTRIBUTE, no matter what is the value.

Comment: I realized it's just the .ogg missing in firefox, so please disregard that aspect.

Comment: remove autoplay="false" in your <video> tag and try again.

Comment: That worked beautifully! There is one aspect that's not incorporated into this solution. If I can press you: how do I also get the video to play when the window is resized from below the breakpoint to above it? A user may load the page on a desktop with a reduced browser window and then enlarge it.

Comment: In that case you only need to register the function to the resize event. I will update my solution to show this case.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do the same thing, after some cross browser testing I found that adding the 'autoplay' attribute dynamically didn't work consistently

( Fine in Firefox, not at all in IE(10), only on document ready / not on resize in Chrome )

So to get it working as expected, instead of

```
$('video').attr('autoplay', true);
```

I used

```
$('video')[0].play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of iOS and Android will not Autoplay videos. They must be started via user interaction.

This has been implemented to avoid users blowing bandwidth limits they may have with their mobile carriers.

The solution, therefore, is to show/hide play controls depending upon the screen widths.

In addition, to avoid unnecessary downloads, you should consider not showing the video at all, and displaying a fallback image or even displaying nothing, if the video does not significantly add to the user experience.