# Prevent load video, that included in <video> tag using CSS

Tags: css, html

I`m use background video in fullscreen on my website. When screen width is smaller than 1200px, I hide video tag using display:none and display picture. But video still continue download, spending mobile traffic. So how i can stop downloading this video on mobile devices using css.

Comment: How can you say it is downloading when it is not visible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable html5 video download at CSS breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027202/disable-html5-video-download-at-css-breakpoint)

Comment: You can't stop the download using css, you need to do it with javascript.

Comment: What if you put it into container with `display: none`?

Comment: @Qwertiy if use display none, it`s continue download. I think i found solution. I can prevent download video, if i change prop of video tag, like $('video').attr('autoplay', false);

Comment: By the way. Maybe it is playing when hidden because it can still produce sound? Or am I wrong?

Comment: It would be better to remove attribute in code and start playing when needed instead of canceling it.